# VBA Select Case Loop in Text

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to loop through a range of cells and assigned a label to them based off of the text value in another cell. So if Cell J2 = "This Text" Then Cell A2 = "This Label"

As of now I keep getting a run time error number 424, stating object required

```
Private Function getPhase(ByVal cell As Range) As String
Select Case cell.Text
    Case "Text1"
        getPhase = "Label1"
    Case "Text2"
        getPhase = "Label2"
End Select
End Function


Sub setPhase()
Dim cycle As Range
Dim phase As Range


Set cycle = Range("J2:J10")
Set phase = Range("A2:A10")

For Each cell In phase.Cells
    phase.Text = getPhase(cycle)
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `cell.value` instead?

Comment: what line does the error occur?

Comment: Just tried it, it fails in "phase.Text = getPhase(cycle)"

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? You can solve this using Excel formula as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already got your answers :) Let me do some explaining in my post though :)

You cannot use this.

```
phase.Text = getPhase(cycle)
```

`.Text` is a **Readonly** property. i.e you cannot write to it but only read from it. You have to use `.Value`

Secondly you don't need to define the 2nd range if you are picking values from the same row. You can always us the `.Offset` property. See this

```
Option Explicit

Sub setPhase()
    Dim rng As Range, phase As Range

    Set phase = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")

    For Each rng In phase
        rng.Value = getPhase(rng.Offset(, 9))
    Next
End Sub

Function getPhase(ByVal cl As Range) As String
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case "Text1"
            getPhase = "Label1"
        Case "Text2"
            getPhase = "Label2"
    End Select
End Function
```

Also there is nothing wrong with `Select Case cell.Text` since you are only reading from it. However, it is always good to use `.Value`. Reason being the `.Value` property returns the actual value of the cell where as `.Text` property returns the text which is displayed on the screen. The limit of Text is approx 8k characters in higher versions of Excel. The `.Value` on the other hand can store up to 32k characters.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett +1 agreed; I was just rushing to get mine on last night (don't know why as I suspect the OPer won't mark any as the answer)

Comment: I quite like the shortcut of Offset ...just `rng(0,9)` instead of `rng.Offset(0,9)`

Comment: @whytheq: I've only recently started answering on Stack but it *is* addictive isn't it! I also agree that the shortcut is good - I tend not to use it only because I don't remember it but I **do** remember offset in Excel because it is so important in formulae.

Comment: @Siddarth-rout: Yours is definitely a cleaner suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I've changed the loop. This assumes that the two ranges are the same lengths

```
Function getPhase(ByVal cell As Range) As String

   Select Case cell.Value
    Case "Text1"
        getPhase = "Label1"
    Case "Text2"
        getPhase = "Label2"
  End Select


End Function


Sub setPhase()
Dim cycle As Range
Dim phase As Range


Set cycle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myexample").Range("J2:J10")
Set phase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myexample").Range("A2:A10")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To phase.Cells.Count
    phase.Cells(i).Value = getPhase(cycle.Cells(i))
Next i

End Sub
```

...or as siddharth had suggested use a formula.

Or do the formula via VBA:

```
Sub setPhase()

Dim phase As Range
Set phase = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
phase.Value = "=IF(J2=""Text1"",""Label1"",IF(J2=""Text2"",""Label2"",""""))"

End Sub
```

Comment: The phase.value may be right but this doesn't use the cycle range at all now.

Comment: true - need to edit further - defintitely needs to use cell in the loop ; otherwise no point having the loop

Comment: @JulianKnight give me a +1 then

Comment: Hmm, maybe. If you put the private back in!

Comment: @JulianKnight: It's called [sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship)!

Comment: @whytheq: Only if I get to do it in a Porsche! Sportsmanship is for loooserrrrs!! Well not really, after all, I did actually give you the +1.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my version:

```
Private Function getPhase(ByVal cell As Range) As String
    Select Case cell.Text
        Case "Text1"
            getPhase = "Label1"
        Case "Text2"
            getPhase = "Label2"
    End Select
End Function


Sub setPhase()
    Dim cycle As Range
    Dim phase As Range


    Set cycle = ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b10")
    Set phase = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10")

    For Each cell In phase.Cells
        cell.Value = getPhase(cycle.Cells(cell.Row, 1))
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 was just doing this myself. Also worth noting to @Salmonerd that Declaring a Variable as `Cell` is bad practice, given that it's a predefined VBA object. Better to use, say, `Cel` or `myCell`

Comment: Good point about cell. I have a bad habit of using my... (so I would normally us "mycell") due to using too many different languages and never remembering which words are reserved!

Comment: @Scott loads of text books use `cell` - it's not bad practice; if it was a reserved word then the procedure wouldn't run.

Comment: @Scott: No, it isn't... You must be thinking of `Cells` with an `s`?

Comment: Alt+F11 > F2 > Search for `Cell`

Comment: @whytheq: good call. Indeed, "cell" isn't in the library reference nor in the help & it *is* allowed as a variable. I don't get too worked up about such things since they change so much between languages. If in doubt use something that you know will work & not cause odd errors.

Comment: @JulianKnight - true but using `cell` is very common in lots of the testbooks aswell; I'd say `For Each cell in...` **is** the convention that I see used more than anything else

Comment: @JulianKnight - here's a link with me getting schooled on this very question back in 2004: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/please-help-need-code-check-t973899.html.  Pretty boring stuff but it cracks me up I can remember the discussion and google it in two minutes.